# mysql precision only if decimal

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal, precision

how to store decimal value in database with 2 decimal precision only if the number is in decimal and has more than two decimal places
like

**10.00** should store **10**

**10.0** should store **10**

**10** should store **10**

**10.1** should store **10.1**

**10.12** should store **10.12**

**10.123** should store **10.12**

**10.1234** should store **10.12**

I've tried these so far and none of them work

```
FLOAT(20,2)
DOUBLE(20,2)
DECIMAL(20,2)
```

All of these are converting simple **10** into **10.00**

I want to set this column type not want to use in query.

Comment: What should "10.10" store as?

Comment: it should be 10.1

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing how something is stored with how it is presented.  In all cases, you want to store the value as `decimal(20, 2)`, because you only seem to care about 2 digits of precision.

When you output it, then you want to convert it to a string.  If commas are acceptable in the larger numbers, then something like:

```
select (case when col = floor(col) then format(col, 0)
             when col*10 = floor(col * 10) then format(col, 1)
             else format(col, 2)
        end) as col_as_string
```

Comment: I want to set this column type not want to use in query.

Comment: There is no DATATYPE that does what you ask for.